# How do I add my parameter to the function where the property initializers run before 'self'?

Tags: swiftui

Error: Cannot use instance member 'makeRandomImage' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

I am trying to create "cgImage" with "makeRandomImage(width: 1024, height: 1024)!" but for some reason there is an error. I am converting a ciImage to a uiImage for my image classifier, but it won't let me add it inside the function parameters.

```
import SwiftUI
import Accelerate

class ImageClassifier: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private var classifier = Classifier()
    
    var imageClass: String? {
        classifier.results
    }
    
    func makeRandomImage(width: Int, height: Int) -> CGImage? {

        let imageFormat = vImage_CGImageFormat(
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bitsPerPixel: 8 * 3,
            colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
            bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue))!
        
        let arrayDescriptor = BNNSNDArrayDescriptor.allocate(
            randomIn: Pixel_8(0) ... 255,
            shape: .matrixRowMajor(width * imageFormat.componentCount,
                                   height))
        
        let imageBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: arrayDescriptor.data,
                                        height: vImagePixelCount(height),
                                        width: vImagePixelCount(width),
                                        rowBytes: width)
        
        return try? imageBuffer.createCGImage(format: imageFormat)
    }
    
    

    let cgImage = makeRandomImage(width: 1024,
                                  height: 1024)!
    let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage)
    
    // MARK: Intent(s)
    func detect(uiImage: uiImage) {
        guard let ciImage = CIImage (image: uiImage) else { return }
        classifier.detect(ciImage: ciImage)
        
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests, you can't call functions on `self` during the initialization stage of a `struct` or `class`.

Luckily, since your `makeRandomImage` function doesn't make use of any other properties from the `struct`, it could easily be made `static`, which *can* be accessed during `init`.

Secondly, you'll run into the same issue with your `uiImage` variable, which you can make into a computed property:

```
static func makeRandomImage(width: Int, height: Int) -> CGImage? {

    let imageFormat = vImage_CGImageFormat(
        bitsPerComponent: 8,
        bitsPerPixel: 8 * 3,
        colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
        bitmapInfo: CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue))!
    
    let arrayDescriptor = BNNSNDArrayDescriptor.allocate(
        randomIn: Pixel_8(0) ... 255,
        shape: .matrixRowMajor(width * imageFormat.componentCount,
                               height))
    
    let imageBuffer = vImage_Buffer(data: arrayDescriptor.data,
                                    height: vImagePixelCount(height),
                                    width: vImagePixelCount(width),
                                    rowBytes: width)
    
    return try? imageBuffer.createCGImage(format: imageFormat)
}



let cgImage = Self.makeRandomImage(width: 1024,
                              height: 1024)!
var uiImage: UIImage { UIImage(cgImage: cgImage) }
```

All that being said, this is a pretty expensive thing to run on a SwiftUI `View` `init`, which should be a very *inexpensive* operation.

You should consider running this in something like `onAppear` or `task` instead.

Comment: Really it should be done in the background, using the `.task` modifier if the deployment target supports it.

Comment: Error: Cannot find type 'uiImage' in scope. I get this error for the function detect that uses uiImage as a parameter. I'll look up how to do .task modifier in the meantime. Thank your help.

Comment: @ColorTheory42 uiImage is definitely in scope (in fact, it's a parameter of the `detect` function... Sounds like a separate issue to me. If you feel that it is closely related, you can edit your original question to show the place with the error.